# ADF wrong datetime format pulled from SQL Server

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory

I have trouble with converting datetime variable to correct format.
When I query

```
select CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, max(Date_U)) as Max_Date_U
  FROM [MDM].[C_CARD_RAWDATA]
```

in SQL server I got: **2022-03-22 15:51:00**

However, when ADF does it, I got **2022-03-22T15:51:00Z** as variable.

How can I convert this strange datetime with **T** and **Z** to normal one without those letters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting it directly do string solved the problem

```
    select CONVERT(varchar,CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, max(Date_U)), 120)  as Max_Date_U
  FROM [MDM].[C_CARD_RAWDATA]
```

Comment: It is safer to declare a length for the varchar